# Importing multiple csv files of data into H2O flow

Tags: csv, h2o

I am having trouble importing multiple csv files on H2O flow. The coffee code from Flow is

```
setupParse paths:["file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv"...]
```

However when the parsing is done I am left only with `file1.hex` and I am not sure where the other files went.

Answer (score 1):

What has happened is that is that all three files have been loaded into a single data frame.

E.g. I just tried with three files with 381 lines, 553 lines, and 553 lines, and got a 1484 row data frame. (I.e. it correctly recognized the header row in each csv file.)

That appears to be no way to load three files into three data frames with a single Flow command. You will need to call the Flow commands three times, once for each file.